# What is the current risk regarding hyper-threading?

Tags: firmware, bios, cpu

We are around four years after [ZombieLoad](https://zombieloadattack.com/).

We had multiple Microcode and OS mitigation patches.

Is enabling hyper-threading still bad practice if firmware, microcode and OS patches for your system are up-to-date?